# Is it acceptable to have NULL foreign keys?

Tags: mysql, sql

This should be a simple question I think, but is it OK to have NULL foreign keys?

I guess to elaborate, let's say I'm making a database for users and different types of users require different data sets... what would be the best practice to design this database?

This was my thought, as a rough example: (am i correct or way off?)

"users": 
id | type (ie. '1' for basic, '2' for advanced) | basic_id (nullable foreign key) | advanced_id (nullable foreign key) | email | name | address | phone (etc etc)

"users_basic": 
id | user_id (foreign key) | (other data only required for basic users)

"users_advanced"
id | user_id (forgein key) | (other data only required for advanced users)

I get the feeling it's bad design cause there's no way to get all the data in one query without checking what type of user it is first, but I really don't like the idea of having ONE table with a ton of NULL data. What is the best way to design this?

Comment: Why would you create a bunch of *orphan* records?

Comment: @PM77-1 well my thinking is because different types of users would have much different types of data stored and I don't want to have one giant table with every row having 50% NULL columns because of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it is fine to have `NULL` foreign keys.

In your case, though, I'd be inclined to do one of two things.  If there really aren't very many columns for the basic and advanced users, you can just include them in the `users` table.  This would be the typical approach.

Otherwise, you can declare `user_id` as the primary key in all three tables, and still have a foreign key relationship from the secondary tables (`users_basic` and `users_advanced`) to the primary (`users`).  Maintaining the distinctiveness of the relationship is tricky in MySQL and probably not worth doing.

Comment: lets say there was a lot of unique data for the different types of users... would you say better practice is to have one giant table where every row would end up having lots of NULL fields? or 3 seperate tables as described above with only 1 of 2 foreign keys being NULL?

I usually DO design it the former way but I'm trying to re-think my design a little bit to the latter and have cleaner databases... I'm just not sure if it's a better or worse solution.

Comment: @StephenFox . . . Separating out the columns into different tables is a very reasonable solution.  Separate table can speed queries, reduce data size, and help implement security requirements.

Comment: Great thanks so much Gordon...another follow up question, what would be the best way to get all of the data for a specific user in ONE query? is that possible or would I have to query the users table to get the type and then query the appropriate second table... I'm assuming doing a double JOIN with NULL keys would not work?

Comment: You would use a `LEFT JOIN` between the master table and the two slave tables.